# how can i access internals in asp.net 5

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, internalsvisibleto

Before asp.net 5 I would add "internalsVisibleTo(some.namespace.name)" to AssemblyInfo.cs - But I no longer have assemblyInfo.cs in my WebApi project.

How do I expose internals in a WebAPI project to my unitTest project?

Comment: I would've assumed the [project.json](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file) file, but I can't find it in the schema.

Answer (score 21):

You can add your own AssemblyInfo.cs file. Just add a class file, name it AssemblyInfo.cs (or any name for that matter), and replace all of its code with the following line:

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("some.assembly.name")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see an example of the above answer in action in the asp open sourced MVC project available on github:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e2fd41e416ce1d84e13734ebfb56e64094607d01/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

One of the best ways of figuring this stuff out is to get in there and have a dig about.

Good luck.

Comment: File doesn't exist. Maybe you should link to a certain commit.

Comment: changed to an example commit where the code exists.

Comment: @ahammond Can't seem to get this working. Even after creating the AssemblyInfo.cs file. Is this still the way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

While creating an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file is an option, I prefer to configure this in my project file.

Add this to your `.csproj` file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
    <_Parameter1>$(AssemblyName).Tests</_Parameter1>
  </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>
```