# Get data from JsonResult

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc

The code is in ASP.NET Core. MVC controller returns Json(someData). 
I am trying to retrieve the data in the Unit test. The best I can do is to have

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult.Value);
```

and then compare the string. But I would prefer to get an object or an array to be able to do some more specific comparisons. Interesting, under debugger I can see that `jsonResult.Value` is of type `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<MyType>` and there is even Results View that warns not to expand it or else; and if I expand it, I get exactly what I want! In my case it is a 4-element array of `MyType` objects. However, if I do something like `from i in jsonResult.Value select i` I get an error

```
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'object'. 
'Select' not found
```

I hope there is a better way than comparing a JSON string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Cast method

`(from i in jsonResult.Value.Cast<MyType>() select i)`

**Edit: updated answer**

```
 from i in ((IQueryable< MyType >)js.Value) select i
```

Comment: I guess you just need to cast jsonresult.Value .. try from i in ((IQueryable< MyType >)js.Value) select i

Comment: Awesome! I tried `js.Value as IQueryable<MyType >` and it didn't work; but for some reason didn't try `(IQueryable<MyType >)js.Value`. Do you mind updating your answer, so I can accept it! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Felix check this answer pertaining to accessing the anonymous types http://stackoverflow.com/a/38446754/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi - thank you saw much. It's so unfortunate that neither the title nor the tags mention JSON, so it never came in my search!