# How to extract values from a JsonResult?

Tags: json, jsonresult

How to extract values from a JsonResult, possibly as a list of Name-Value pairs ?
Coding on ASP.Net Core 3.1

Here is my code from Controller in short:

```
JsonResult jsonStr = CalcPrint(); 
...
...
public JsonResult CalcPrint()
{
    int usuage;
    double bAmt
    ...
    ...
    var calcResult = new { usuage, bamt = bAmt };
    return Json(calcResult);
}
```

Debugging shows jsonStr.Value as follows:

{ usuage = 1200, bamt = 1875 }

I can assign this value to a string var and then split it; but not the right way i think.
Any other ways to get it possibly as a list ?

Comment: You should elaborate more on your question, starting with mentioning what language you use for reference

Comment: Sorry. Edited and hope its clear now..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get data from JsonResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537861/get-data-from-jsonresult)