# Asserting for equality anonymous types

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, anonymous-types

I faced a problem asserting two anonymous types.

#### What I've done so far

- I have unit test project which sees the internals of my project under test, so anonymous types are visible to test project.
- I've read about anonymous types behaving more like structures(value types) rather than reference types here: [Why anonymous types Equals implementation compares fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123512/why-anonymous-types-equals-implementation-compares-fields)

Yet again, while trying to test again equality following assertion exceptions occur:

1.

```
Assert.IsTrue(actionResult.Value.Equals(expectedActionResult.Value));
```

> Expected: True   But was:  False

2.

```
Assert.AreEqual(actionResult.Value, expectedActionResult.Value);
```

> Expected: <{ errorCode = -4, errorMessage = Invalid or Missing parameters within the request. }> (<>f__AnonymousType0'2[System.Int32,System.String])
>     But was:  <{ errorCode = -4, errorMessage = Invalid or Missing parameters within the request. }> (<>f__AnonymousType0'2[System.Int32,System.String])

This is where I create real and expected result:

```
var actionResult = _systemUnderTest.GetToken(null) as JsonResult;
var expectedActionResult = 
    new JsonResult(new
    {
        errorCode = (int)ErrorCodes.InvalidOrMissingParameters, errorMessage = ErrorCodes.InvalidOrMissingParameters.GetDescription()
    });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You could also take a look at the answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439811/how-do-you-unit-test-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers-that-return-anonymous-objects/38446754#38446754

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the anonymous types are *accessible* in your test project, that doesn't mean they'll be used when you write `new { ... }`.

If you look at `actionResult.Value.GetType()` and `expectedActionResult.Value.GetType()` I strongly suspect you'll see that they're different types from different assemblies.

The simplest workaround in this case is probably just to compare the resulting JSON instead.

Comment: `actionResult.Value.GetType().Module.ScopeName` and `expectedActionResult.Value.GetType().ScopeName` yielded their different assemblies, but apart from that at first glance everything else was the same, even the `UnderlyingSystemType` which is strange doesn't compiler generate these names every time and does that mean that anonymous types can't be tested across assemblies?

Comment: @kuskmen: If they're in different assemblies, everything else is completely irrelevant - they're different types. The equality comparison in anonymous types first checks that the types are the same, as is common for equality checks.

Comment: From what I've saw while debugging generated code by the compiler I noticed that casting from object to that particular compiler generated anonymous type fails therefore Equals method returns false.

`[DebuggerHidden]
 public override bool Equals(object value)
 {
  var <>f__AnonymousType = value as <>f__AnonymousType0<<a>j__TPar>;
  return <>f__AnonymousType != null && EqualityComparer<<a>j__TPar>.Default.Equals(this.<a>i__Field, <>f__AnonymousType.<a>i__Field);
 }`