# How to assert with anonymous type result in unit testing web API?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, mstest

Hi I am writing unit test cases for the following method in my controller.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetList")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllMasterList()
    {
        var MasterList = _masterListRepo.GetAll().Select(t => new { t.MASTER_ID, t.MASTER_NAME }).OrderBy(t=>t.MASTER_NAME).ToList();
        return Ok(MasterList);
    }
```

For the above method the unit test case method is as follows.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AllMastersList()
    {
        //Arrange
        var controller = new MastersController();
        var actualResults = _masterListRepo.GetAll().ToList();

        //Act
        var actionResult = controller.GetAllMasterList();

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(actionResult.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<>));
        var contentExpected = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<dynamic>>;
        Assert.IsNotNull(contentExpected.Content.ToList());
        Assert.AreEqual(contentExpected.Content.Count(), actualResults.Count);

    }
```

I am getting `contentExpected` as `null`. How do I cast this `Ok()` result to get the value. How to do it?

Comment: Take a look at the answer I gave here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38446754/5233410

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommed against returning anonymous objects.
Introduce a model class with will allow you to easily unit test you api calls.

```
public class Master {
    public string Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
}

var MasterList = _masterListRepo.GetAll().Select(t => new Master {Id = MASTER_ID, Name = t.MASTER_NAME).OrderBy(t=>t.MASTER_NAME).ToList();
```

Also you don't have to return an IHttpActionResult from your Method, you can just return an IEnumerable with also makes your test way more readable

```
var controller = new MastersController();
var actualResults = _masterListRepo.GetAll().ToList();

var resultsFromController = controller.GetAllMasterList(); //This is now an IEnumerable<Master>)
```

Comment: totally got your point. But there must be some way to test such methods. Which returns anonymous lists.